# Getting error while importing image through database via link in phpword

Tags: php, phpword

I am generating **word docx**. with **phpword**, i want to add image in my docx file via **URL**, the **url** links are in my **SQL table** with the name of **imageUrlPrint**, how can i print image ?

I already tried this but won't help me!

```
$source = 'http://php.net/images/logos/php-med-trans-light.gif';
$section->addText("Remote image from: {$source}");
$section->addImage($source)
```

Comment: Check what the PHP config option `allow_url_fopen` is set to first of all.

Comment: I did'nt get you bro! but nope i do not set it anywhere though.

Comment: Call `phpinfo();`, and look for the mentioned setting in the output.

Comment: allow_url_fopen = on in php.ini and i'm using xampp

Comment: Can you post the output of a `file_get_contents` on the URL?

Comment: I am getting this erro ` Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\InvalidImageException: Invalid image: in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Element\Image.php:418 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Element\Image.php(149): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Image->checkImage() #1 [internal function]: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Image->__construct('')` and my code link is this you can see whole code here [link](https://codeshare.io/UbKVU)